# extract the rows in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the structure . And I have **many** `<div class="extra">` like this in my project.

```
<div class="extra">
    <table width="90%">
        <colgroup>
        <col width="40%"/>
        <col width="30%"/>
        <col width="30%"/>
        </colgroup>
        <tr><td>/*.1.*/</td><td>/*.1.*/</td><td>/*.1.*/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>/*.2.*/</td><td>/*.2.*/</td><td>/*.2.*/</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I reform each of the div into this:

```
<div class="line">
    <table width="90%">
        <colgroup>
        <col width="40%"/>
        <col width="30%"/>
        <col width="30%"/>
        </colgroup>
        <tr><td>/*.1.*/</td><td>/*.1.*/</td><td>/*.1.*/</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="line">
    <table width="90%">
        <colgroup>
        <col width="40%"/>
        <col width="30%"/>
        <col width="30%"/>
        </colgroup>
        <tr><td>/*.2.*/</td><td>/*.2.*/</td><td>/*.2.*/</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

principles:

1. Each column of the table should be extracted and reform a single table.
2. New table is nested in new `<div class="line">`
3. The style of `<div class="line">` and `<colgroup>`should be kept as origin.

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qSbst/), the control panel says "Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 "

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Lilith2K3 sorry I forgot to attach the fiddle...

Comment: The HTML and Principle 1 seem to be at odds with each other. Maybe I misunderstand but it looks like you want to extract rows, not columns. Column structure within each row appears to remain intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a problem like this, you will find it easier to work wholly in jQuery rather than hybrid code.

Here, are two functions, the first of which orchestrates the transforms, and the second performs the required transform of a single `.extra` div.

The transform is achieved by cloning (repeatedly) the original, complete with all its table rows, then removing all but one table row from the clone. The surviving, row in each clone, is determined by the index of the clone.

The clones occupy the same position in the DOM as the original, which is removed.

```
function transformMaster() {
    $(".extra").each(function(i, div) {
        extra2lines($(div));
    });
}
function extra2lines($div) {
    var $rows = $div.find("table tr"),
        n = $rows.length;
    $rows.each(function(i) {
        var $clone = $div.clone(true, true).removeClass('extra').addClass('line').insertAfter($div);
        $clone.find("table tr").each(function(j) {
            if(i !== (n-j-1)) $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $div.remove();
}
```

Then, all you need to do is call `transformMaster()`.

The only tricky bit is `if(i !== (n-j-1))`, which allows for the fact that `insertAfter($div)` inserts the clones in "reverse order" - each clone *above* the previous one. This is much easier than inserting the clones in the "correct" order.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q7Xyv/)** You will see that I gave `.line td` a background-color so you can see that the transform has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with this script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var $extra = $('.extra');
        $extra.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this).clone();
            $this.find('tr').remove();
            $.each($(this).find('tr'), function () {
                var newdiv = $this.clone().find('table').append(this).end().removeClass('extra').addClass('line');
                $('body').append(newdiv);
            });
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is quite straightforward, it means the element you want to append is not found.

In your script:

```
linediv.appendChild(individual);
```

The *linediv* is a DOM node object, while the *individual* is a jQuery collection object. And the linediv 's appendChild function expects a DOM node object, not a jQuery object. So just substitute that line with either:

```
linediv.appendChild(individual[0]);
```

or

```
$(linediv).append(individual);
```